# error in creating new hook method in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have written a plugin module for PostgreSQL for my academic requirements(version: PostgreSQL9.3.4) I am using hooks to influence planner behaviour in this plugin module. I am able to use join_search_hook, planner_hook successfully. But I wanted to create a new hook for a method which is not already having a hook defined.

I wanted to define a hook for

```
void set_baserel_size_estimates(PlannerInfo *root, RelOptInfo *rel)
```

method in **costsize.c**

I declared a hook in **optimizer/paths.h**

```
typedef void (*size_estimates_hook_type) (PlannerInfo *root, RelOptInfo *rels);
extern PGDLLIMPORT size_estimates_hook_type size_estimates_hook;
```

and initialized it at top of **allpaths.c**

```
size_estimates_hook_type size_estimates_hook = NULL;
```

I added this check in allpaths.c in a method to decide whether to invoke hooked method or not.

```
if (size_estimates_hook)
    (*size_estimates_hook) (root, rel);
else
    set_baserel_size_estimates(root, rel);
```

Now coming to plugin module code,

```
static join_search_hook_type prev_join_search = NULL;
static size_estimates_hook_type prev_size_estimates = NULL;
```

The first line compiles fine, but second line gives error

```
"error: unknown type name ‘size_estimates_hook_type’"
```

Am i missing some step in defining a new hook method?
note: Plugin is compiled using a dedicated Makefile.

Comment: At a guess, your module isn't including the `optimizer/paths.h` you've modified. Are you using PGXS, or in-tree compiling the module in `contrib/mymodulename`? If you're using a homebrew Makefile, stop *now* and use PGXS. Use the existing plugins for guidance, and [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-pgxs.html). Excellent question btw, all the details except the actual Makefile.

Comment: @CraigRinger: As you guessed, makefile was the problem. I will post the working makefile here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following makefile for compiling the plugin module solved the issue.

```
MODULES = module_name
ifdef USE_PGXS
PG_CONFIG = <path to /backend/bin/pg_config>
PGXS := $(shell $(PG_CONFIG) --pgxs)
include $(PGXS)
else
subdir = contrib/module_name
top_builddir = ../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global
include $(top_srcdir)/contrib/contrib-global.mk
endif
```